# .htaccess redirection resulting in infinite loop in my local

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to redirect the mobile traffic from one domain to another, and the desktop traffic too.

So when I go to www.a.com which is the desktop domain, with a mobile, .htaccess redirects to m.a.com. And when I go to m.a.com with a desktop, .htaccess redirects to www.a.com

This is working normal in a test server which uses desktop.domain.com and mobile.domain.com.

I tried it on my local with a domain like www.local.com and m.local.com but I get inifinite redirection loop when accessing the mobile version with a mobile UA, but not with a desktop UA.

THis is my desktop.a.com .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^desktop
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|#opera mobile|palmos|webos" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} desktop\.local\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://mobile.local.com [L,R=302]
```

This is my mobile.a.com .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mobile\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|opera\smobile|palmos|webos) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.local.com [L,R=302]
```

As a side note, several images are missing in my local because I don't have those.

Comment: Do you have a desktop.local.com mapped to an IP in your host file? Also is apache setup to listen on any IP?

Comment: Yeah, everything is ok with that, I can see both mobile and desktop on local, but when accessing the mobile version with a mobile UA is when Chrome says Infinite redirection loop